# Yii2 dynamic form (File upload)

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions

I want to use dynamic form in yii2(http://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions) here is my code:
[image]

part of **controller**:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $modelsProductImage = $model->images;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsProductImage, 'id', 'id');
        $modelsProductImage = Model::createMultiple(ProductImage::classname(), $modelsProductImage);
        Model::loadMultiple($modelsProductImage, Yii::$app->request->post());
        $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsProductImage, 'id', 'id')));

        foreach ($modelsProductImage as $index => $modelProductImage) {
            $modelProductImage->sort_order = $index;
            $modelProductImage->product_id = $model->id;
            //echo $modelProductImage->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($modelProductImage, "[{$index}]file");
            $file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName($index);
            print_r($file);
        }
    }    
}
```

and this is my **view** file:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'dynamic-form',
    'options' => [
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
    ],

]); ?>

<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
    'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
    'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
    //'limit' => 4, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
    'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
    'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
    'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
    'model' => $modelsProductImage[0],
    'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
    'formFields' => [
        'id',
        //'path',
        'product_id',
    ],

]); ?>

<?php foreach ($modelsProductImage as $index => $modelProductImage): ?>
    <div class="item panel panel-default col-md-3"><!-- widgetBody -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="panel-title-address"><?= Yii::t('app','Image').':'. ($index + 1) ?></span>
            <button type="button" class="pull-left remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php

            // necessary for update action.
            if (!$modelProductImage->isNewRecord) {
                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelProductImage, "[{$index}]id");
            }
            ?>
            <?php
            $modelImage = $modelProductImage;
            $initialPreview = [];
            if ($modelImage) {
                $pathImg =  '/'.$modelImage->path;

                $initialPreview[] = Html::img($pathImg, ['class' => 'file-preview-image']);
            }
            ?>

            <div class="">
                <?= $form->field($modelProductImage, "[{$index}]file")->label(false)->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                  'options' => [
                      'multiple' => false,
                      'accept' => 'image/*',
                      'class' => 'productImage-path',
                      'name' => $index
                  ],
                  'pluginOptions' => [
                      'previewFileType' => 'image',
                      'showCaption' => false,
                      'showUpload' => false,
                      'browseClass' => 'btn btn-default btn-sm',
                      //'browseLabel' => Yii::t('app',' Pick Image'),
                      'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>',
                      'removeClass' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm',
                        //'removeLabel' => ' Delete',
                      'removeIcon' => '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',
                      'previewSettings' => [
                          'image' => ['width' => '138px', 'height' => 'auto']
                      ],
                      'initialPreview' => $initialPreview,
                      'layoutTemplates' => ['footer' => '']
                  ]
                ]) ?>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When i use getInstanceByName in controller it only return one file, and when i use getInstance it return NULL

and when i use getInstanceByname it save new file on old file(not as a new file)

Comment: You have showed an actionUpdate .. this update only  .. not add new files...there is not the code for new object ..

Answer (score 1):

Are you see example? [docs](http://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo2/source-code#controller)

This is part of example from docs:

```
...
$modelsOptionValue = Model::createMultiple(OptionValue::classname());
Model::loadMultiple($modelsOptionValue, Yii::$app->request->post());
foreach ($modelsOptionValue as $index => $modelOptionValue) {
    $modelOptionValue->sort_order = $index;
    $modelOptionValue->img = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($modelOptionValue, "[{$index}]img");
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstances()?

You can check the details [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html)